# Get IP Address of user/client viewing report in SSRS 2008 Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ip-address

There must be a way to do this. I simply need a way to expose the IP address (or computer name - but I think IP is easier to get) of the user who is viewing a report on an SQL 2008 (not r2) report server. Here is what I have already tried:

1. Writing code in the report code block to get the IP address such as:

   ```
   Public Function GetClientIP() As String
       Dim sReturn As String = ""
       Dim ipHost As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())

       For i As int32 = 0 To ipHost.AddressList.Length - 1
           If (Not ipHost.AddressList(i) Is Nothing AndAlso ipHost.AddressList(i).ToString().Trim() <> "" AndAlso ipHost.AddressList(i).ToString().Length() <= 15) Then
               sReturn = ipHost.AddressList(i).ToString()
           End If
       Next i

       Return sReturn
   End Function
   ```

   At first this gave me all kinds of security permission errors and I was able to get around it by changing the PermissionSet for Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions to FullTrust in rssrvpolicy.config:

   ```
   <CodeGroup
     class="UnionCodeGroup"
     version="1"
     PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
     Name="Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions"
     Description="This code group grants default permissions for code in report expressions and Code element. ">
     <IMembershipCondition
     class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
     version="1"
     PublicKeyBlob="0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100512C8E872E28569E733BCB123794DAB55111A0570B3B3D4DE3794153DEA5EFB7C3FEA9F2D8236CFF320C4FD0EAD5F677880BF6C181F296C751C5F6E65B04D3834C02F792FEE0FE452915D44AFE74A0C27E0D8E4B8D04EC52A8E281E01FF47E7D694E6C7275A09AFCBFD8CC82705A06B20FD6EF61EBBA6873E29C8C0F2CAEDDA2"
     />
   </CodeGroup>
   ```

   And after all that I found out that it is returning the server IP address instead of the client! That's not what [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sqlreportingservices/thread/a1a1e850-ed9c-44c1-928e-b9549ad79413) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ff58b2fe-5fa7-4f2b-b36d-9685fc9f74fd) say.
2. I tried different ASP.net variables such as `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` which

   1. only works when it is deployed and throws an error when running from debugger (I suppose this is to be expected) and
   2. It also returns the server IP address only!

   In fact I wrote a quick script to grab all the server variables and display it on the report screen, but none of it contains the client IP address!

   ```
   Public Function GetServerVariables() AS String
       Dim sReturn as String = ""

       for i as int32 = 0 to System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Count -1
           sReturn &=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Keys(i).ToString & ": " & System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item(i).ToString() & " - "
       next i

       Return sReturn
   End Function
   ```
3. I tried creating a custom assembly in vb.NET which basically runs the exact same code as the GetClientIP() function above but I was not able to resolve the permission errors with that one after a couple days of trying. I eventually gave up on this because around the same time I got the report code from step (1) working and since it was returning the server IP address I assumed that the custom assembly would return the same thing.

So there we have it. Sorry about the long-winded explanation but I wanted to be as thorough as possible. And for those who want to know WHY I need the users IP address, it is actually another complicated story and I will explain it in another post if someone really wants to know.

Bottom line is, I need the IP address or computer name of the computer that is running the report in their browser. The username or any other details will not suffice unless they can be used to lookup the IP address somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love for someone to give me a simpler solution to finding the users ip address when running a report, but here is *a* working solution that I was able to hack together in a couple weeks.

First of all, I had no luck with custom assemblies or the report code block, as all I got was the servers ip address instead of the client. Instead, I decided to play with jquery in the report manager aspx pages to do the dirty work.

Here are the steps as straightforward as I can put them:

1) Create a new file called GetClientIPAddress.aspx in the Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Server\MSRS10.Instancename\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Pages directory. The content of the GetClientIPAddress.aspx is one line as follows:

```
<%=Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]%>
```

This is the page that will actually get the clients ip address.

2) Edit the Folder.aspx file in the same folder and add this javascript code at the bottom of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    try {
        var sReportName = 'Name of report here'

        $("a").each(function() {
            if (this.innerText == sReportName  || this.textContent == sReportName)
            {
                this.href = this.href.replace('Report.aspx','ReportEx.aspx');
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) { }
});
</script>
```

Replace the 'Name of report here' with the name of your report. The report name is by default the filename of the report minus the extension. You can find and change this value in the report "Properties" tab > "General" sub tab > "Name" field.

3) Finally, create a new file in the same folder called ReportEx.aspx. This file is based off of and uses the same header as the Report.aspx file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MSRS" Namespace="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI" Assembly="ReportingServicesWebUserInterface" %>
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Report.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportWrapperPage" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

$(document.body).ready(function () {
    try {
        var sItemPath = getUrlVars()["ItemPath"];
        var sSelectedTab = getUrlVars()["SelectedTabId"];

        if (sSelectedTab === undefined || sSelectedTab == 'ViewTab')
        {
            $("table.msrs-normal").each(function() {
                if (this.rows.length == 2 && this.rows[0].cells.length == 1)
                {
                    var sIPAddress = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'GetClientIPAddress.aspx',
                        async: false
                    }).responseText;

                    this.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML = '<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" src="http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?'+sItemPath+'&rs:Command=Render&IPAddress='+sIPAddress+'"></iframe>';
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
});
</script>
```

Replace 'servername' with the ip address or computer name of the server running the report/sql server.

This "hack" works by effectively intercepting the anchor tag href link to your report and replacing it with an almost identical link that goes to ReportEx.aspx instead of Report.aspx. On the ReportEx page, an ajax javascript call is made to the GetClientIPAddress.aspx page which returns the client ip address. The report is effectively hidden or erased through javascript and is replaced with an iframe of the exact same report. The only difference is that the new report has the ip address set as a query string parameter which is passed directly into the report this time. This of course requires that you create a parameter in your report called 'IPAddress' so that it will properly be accepted once we have done all this work to get it there!

So there we have it. If anyone can think of a better way to do this, or even a way to simplify some of my steps, I would love to hear about it! This was done on SQL Server 2008, and I imagine that this solution could work on earlier and newer versions but possibly with slight alterations of the code. As roundabout as this solution is, I am providing it in the hope that someone else may benefit from my hours and hours spent trying to figure out *A* way, *ANY* way to do this!

Comment: Hi @Joseph, I know its been a long time you wrote this answer but i got to ask a question. Im now struggling the same issue on SQL 2016 and could not find a way to get the client IP address in the visual studio reporting project to send it to my sql query as a parameter. I have been trying your solution for hours maybe but couldnt make it because there is no folder.aspx in 2016 version and some other things (like filenames etc. ) are also different from yours. So i was wondering if you could help me on this ? Maybe you did the same work on 2016 sql too.?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to return the client IP and had no success either. However, I thought I'd tell you what I did in case it suggested something further to you or if your environment works differently to mine. I'm running in SharePoint integration mode.

Firstly, I thought I would bypass the server by passing the IP as a parameter, so I wrote the following function as custom code:

```
Public Function GetIPAddress() As String
    Dim strHostName As String
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()

    Return strIPAddress
End Function
```

Then I had a parameter with the expression:

```
=Code.GetIPAddress()
```

Nice theory, and worked beautifully locally but when deployed the custom code gets evaluated on the server and I got my Reporting Services server IP address, not my local one.

So then I tried the HttpContext with a variety of variables and that was a little better, but not much so:

```
Public Function GetClientIP() As String
    Dim IpAddress As String

    IpAddress = "UserHost: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress + " ClientIP: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") + " Remote: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") +         " Forward: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
   return IpAddress
End Function
```

UserHostAddress gave me the SharePoint server IP, HTTP_CLIENT_IP was blank, REMOTE_ADDR was the SharePoint server IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR was blank.

So it might not be able to be done. In any case, there are [some reasons to avoid using HttpContext in reports](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalla/archive/2009/01/09/avoid-using-httpcontext-in-your-reports.aspx) including that it isn't available in asynchronous threads (which are used to render the report) nor in report subscriptions which aren't executed using a Http request.

Anyway, that's where I got to with it - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your assembly a strongname and fulltrust permission.

Before each call to a .net service you must assert the required permission and immediately revertassert it after the call.

You grant your assembly permissions in the rssrvpolicy.config file.
In Admin tools the .net configuration tool is used to manage code groups and permissions.
I suggest adding a new code group and permission for your custom assemblies.

To use your updates, you will have to stop and restart reporting services.

For reporting services to use your custom assembly, it requires that your custom assembly has
fulltrust.   Once you have the permissions all set, you will get the error message that the
assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

To remedy this, edit your assemblyinfo.vb file and add the following line of code:

Assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()

Encapsulate the the above code with <...>, I removed them because the editor kept 
removing the whole line.

Once you have your permissions fixed, you can use the .net configuration tools to add your custom assembly to the assembly cache.   Note, that each time you make changes to your assembly you will 
need to copy your .dll file to the directory you decided to use.  Remove the assembly from the 
cache and re-add it.  Otherwise, you will always call the old version of your assembly.
When you are in your report project, navigate to reports then references.  Your assembly will be
listed in the .net list of available assemblies.

Also, be very careful with the change you made to Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions.  Giving 
it fulltrust gives all code that runs on your server whether yours or a hacker full access in any expression in any report fulltrust and access.

Remember that the changes in rssrvpolicy.config should be done to rsmgrpolicy.config for report manager.

Its safer to give the required permissions to the custom assembly.
The code would look similar to:

```
    Dim SecurityPermission As New PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)
    Try
        Dim SqlClientPermission As New SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)

        SqlClientPermission.Assert()

        If pSqlCmd() <> vbNullString Then
            cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(pSqlCmd(), con)
        Else
            cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
        End If

    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        SqlClientPermission.RevertAssert()
        SecurityPermission.Assert()
        Authorized = False
        pErrorMsg(ex.ToString())
    Catch ex As System.Security.SecurityException
        SqlClientPermission.RevertAssert()
        SecurityPermission.Assert()
        Authorized = False
        pErrorMsg(ex.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        SqlClientPermission.RevertAssert()
        SecurityPermission.Assert()
        Authorized = False
        pErrorMsg(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        SqlClientPermission.RevertAssert()

    End Try

    The above code does not need SecurityPermission.   I am asserting it because the 
    exception handler assumes I do not have full access to the security system.  
    Its assumption means it gives me less information in the exception message.   By
    asserting SecurityPermission before accessing the exception message, I am able to 
    attain a full explaination of the error.   

    Note as well, that you are only allowed to make one permission assertion at a time.
    There are other methods available to add permissions to a permissionset and then
    assert that permission set.  That is why you see in the above code a RevertAssert
    to remove the current assertion before asserting another. 

   (*** There is no RevertAssert for SecurityPermission.Assert because its reverted when the 
        current routine ends ***)

    When I have time, I will write some documentation on this process.  I painfully worked 
    my way through it.
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:
Enable [Report Server HTTP Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630443.aspx)

To configure the Report Server HTTP log, use Notepad to modify the ReportingServicesService.exe.config file. The configuration file is located in the \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Bin folder.
To enable the HTTP server, you must add http:4 to the RStrace section of the ReportingServicesService.exe.config file. All other HTTP log file entries are optional. The following example includes all settings so that you can paste the whole section over the RStrace section, and then delete the settings you do not need.

```
   <RStrace>
     <add name="FileName" value="ReportServerService_" />
     <add name="FileSizeLimitMb" value="32" />
     <add name="KeepFilesForDays" value="14" />
     <add name="Prefix" value="tid, time" />
     <add name="TraceListeners" value="debugwindow, file" />
     <add name="TraceFileMode" value="unique" />
     <add name="HttpTraceFileName" value="ReportServerService_HTTP_" />
     <add name="HttpTraceSwitches" value="date,time,clientip,username,serverip,serverport,host,method,uristem,uriquery,protocolstatus,bytesreceived,timetaken,protocolversion,useragent,cookiereceived,cookiesent,referrer" />
     <add name="Components" value="all:3,http:4" />
   </RStrace>
```

field ClientIp - The IP address of the client accessing the report server. Please note that there must be no whitespace after commas in the HttpTraceSwitches (or else SSRS will silently ignore it).

Comment: I downvoted this because even tough it makes sense, theres a bug which logs the server IP instead of the client IP, so this is not actually a working way to find the client IP.

Comment: ok so i tried this again, it works, but for some reason I had the exact same typo that you had in the original answer - there *must not be* any whitespace. I edited your answer to remove the typo.